# Python, "print" and "return" resulted in different boolean logic

Tags: python

I recently started learning python through Sololearn and got to [Recursion](https://www.sololearn.com/learning/1073/2465/5112/1). To get better understanding of the code, I simplified it to:

```
def is_even(x):
    return x
def is_odd(x):
    return not is_even(x)
print(is_odd(2))
```

The `return not is_even(x)` is boolean and will resulted it as `False` and when it passed to the  `def is_even(x):` it still would return as False.
However, when I change the `return x` to `print(x)`

```
def is_even(x):
    print (x)
def is_odd(x):
    return not is_even(x)
print(is_odd(2))
```

The result would be:

```
2
True
```

How did this happen? What is going on between the `return not is_even(x)` and `print (x)`.
Thank you

Comment: Pls edit the indentation to match your actual code. Also, there is no recursion in your code.

Comment: That second piece of code does not fit your description, and doesn't run at all. (It is the same as the first but with broken indentation.)

Comment: If `print` is the only statement in the function body, the function implicitly returns `None` which is a falsy value. Thus, `not None` is `True` and should be expected.

Comment: Try `print(is_even(2))` as well, and then look at what `not None` is.

Comment: `not None` = `True`. You function was returning NONE since you are not having any return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will get you on track:

```
def returning(x):
    return x

def printing(x):
    print(x)

returning(2)
# 2

printing(2)
# 2

a = returning(2)
a
# 2

b = printing(2)
2
b
# None
```

The difference is that `return` returns a value from a `function` which can be used to pass to another function / variable. `print` just prints out the information but does not return any value, this is why `b` holds no value, but during the assigment `b = printing(2)` it immediately printed out what was passed to it, when `a = returning(2)` did not, it assigned the value to variable `a`.

And `None` is falsly in python.

```
None == False
# False

None == True
# False

not None == True
# True
```

What you are lacking is for `is_even` to return a `bool` instead of the argument passed:

```
def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0
def is_odd(x):
    return not is_even(x)

is_odd(3)

# True
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not have any recursion!
the function is_even() returns anything you pass to it like an integer,a character or anything else.
the function is_odd() returns a boolean;But notice the equivalent boolean value for non boolean values.
For example values like 1, 'Example', [1,2,3] and ... have True boolean value and values like 0,[], None and ... have False boolean value.
So if you pass something like "test" or 5 to is_odd(), it will return False